# Number of permutations with repetitions that contain a specific subset

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If I have a set is there a way to calculate the number of permutations with repetitions that contain a specific subset of digits.

Specifically, I'm looking for a specific formula that takes in as parameters the length of the set  and the length of the subset of digits.

For example, if I have the set with a length of 3, {0, 1, 2}, I know there are 3^3 = 27 permutations with repetitions if the permutations are of length 3:

{000, 001, 002, 010, 011, 012, 020, 021, 022,
100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112, 120, 121, 122,
200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 220, 221, 222}

The number of permutations with repetitions containing the unique digits (represented as subsets) of length 2, e.g., {0,1}, {0,2}, {1, 2} is 12 since 12 of the permutations always contain these sets of length 2.

From my understanding this number is always constant and irrespective of the actual values in the set, i.e., the number of permutations of length N with repetitions that contain the subset of digits of length n where n <= N is always constant, so to me, it feels like there should be some closed form expression to calculate it.

Comment: Inclusion Exclusion works here.  Start with the unrestricted number, remove all those that are missing one specified element, then add those that are missing two specified elements, and so on.

Comment: okay, so in the case above, assuming I do this with the subset {0, 1}, I would start with 27, realize that 8 subsets do not have 0's and 8 subsets do not have 1's, so 27 - 8 - 8 = 11, then add the cardinality of the intersection of the two subsets I removed which is 1 since the intersection is {222}, hence 27 - 8 - 8 + 1 = 12?  If I'm trying to program a small script for larger values is there any programmatic way to generate the numbers needed to exclude as this problem is basically the reduction of a larger problem I'm working on and I'm trying to avoid calculating actual permutations

Comment: Each step is easy  since you are subtracting terms which are the product of binomial symbols and simple powers.  I wouldn't expect there to be any sort of useful closed formula that holds generally, though of course I might be missing something.